# Is this sexual assault or any other crime?

Tags: england-and-wales, any-jurisdiction, sexual-assault

A [scene](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vTQmxmDJnxU) from the [film](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0398017/) Derailed often invites comments to the effect that the depicted tactic is a good way to end up in the back of a police car. (In it, a man bets a woman he can kiss her without touching her lips before simply kissing her lips, thus forfeiting the wagered $20.)

Is it?

Comment: Unless you explain what the scene depicts **and which film it is from**, the actual content of the question is lacking quite information. I am not going to watch a random youtube video that might be gone or geoblocked.

Comment: "A film" is not the title. A IMDB link is good, **but** you still don't name the film title in the question. Again, **all required information** needs to be in the question,  spelled out, not just linked.

Answer (score 1):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

#### The elements of sexual assault

To prove an offence, the Crown (prosecution) must establish both the [*actus reus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actus_reus) and [*mens rea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_rea) of the offence.

The [*actus reus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actus_reus) of sexual assault is that:

- there is sexual touching;
- there is no consent to that specific sexual touching in the mind of the complainant.

*Criminal Code*, s. 273.1:

> Subject to subsection (2) and subsection 265(3), ***consent*** means, for the purposes of sections 271, 272 and 273, the voluntary agreement of the complainant to engage in the sexual activity in question.

Consent for the purpose of sexual assault is only the subjective consent by the complainant. "For the purposes of the *actus reus* 'consent' means that the complainant in her mind wanted the sexual touching to take place" (*R. v. Ewanchuk*, [[1999] 1 SCR 330](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/item/1684/index.do)).

"The [*mens rea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_rea) is the intention to touch, knowing of, or being reckless of or wilfully blind to, a lack of consent, either by words or actions, from the person being touched" (*R. v. Ewanchuk*, [[1999] 1 S.C.R. 330](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/item/1684/index.do)).

#### A defence: mistaken belief in communicated consent

As part of defending against a charge of sexual assault, and accused may argue that they were under a mistaken belief in communicated consent. This is available when the defendant: (1) has taken reasonable steps to ascertain consent; **and**, (2) has the honest belief that the complainant actually communicated consent.

#### Application: the hypothetical is underspecified

There is not enough information to know whether the *actus reus* of sexual assault is made out. You would have to stipulate whether the complainant subjectively wanted, in her mind, the touching to take place or not. If she wanted it, then there is no sexual assault. If she did not want it, then the analysis proceeds to the accused's awareness of that lack of consent.

There is also not enough information to know whether the kiss was even of a sexual nature.

And there is also not enough information to know whether the accused had the requisite *mens rea*. You would have to stipulate more about the accused's state of mind in order for us to make that evaluation.

Last, there is not enough information to assess whether the defence of "mistaken belief in communicated consent" is available. We would have to know what steps the accused took to ascertain consent and whether, after having taken those steps, the accused honestly believed that the complainant communicated consent.